# I lost my phone and i have very important files in gallery vault

Tags: gallery-vault

if ever they try to open the vault saying they forgot the password, will they successfully open the vault? or if they format the phone or factory reset it, and they open the vault folder, are they going to see the files? PLEASE ANSWER ME AS SOON AS POSSIBLE BECAUSE MY LIFE DEPENDS ON THAT FILES.

Comment: What is gallery vault?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any serious password-protected system that will open up when the person who demands access says "I forgot the password."

There are two options:

**If Vault doesn't use encryption (very likely):**

Then they don't actually have to even crack the password. They  can root the phone and extract the data. I would be able to do it in minutes myself.

**If Vault does use encryption (very unlikely):**

Then it means the data is encrypted and has to be decrypted. From that point on it depends on if the key is static or generated based on an algorithm, the encryption method etc. But if Vault uses a proper encryption method, there is no way they can decrypt you data in this lifetime.